# execute shell script in java application

Tags: java, linux, shell

I am writing java application which gives me Port no. of application which is listening on particular port.

I want to get port no. of application which is listening on port 10001

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lsof -i:10001 | awk '{print $2}'");
InputStream is=p.getInputStream();
byte b[]=new byte[is.available()];
is.read(b,0,b.length);
System.out.println(new String(b));
p.waitFor();
System.out.println("exit: " + p.exitValue());
p.destroy();
```

`lsof -i:10001 | awk '{print $2}'` when i execute this in shell it gets me output

```
PID
8092
```

**But in java application it gives me `exit: 1` . Why doesnt it run in java ? Also can i get just port no only ? i.e. instead of `PID 8091` i want `8092`**

Comment: [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)

Comment: Always remember that pipes are interpreted by the **shell**.

Comment: @Joni i tried that too but doesnt work

Comment: "Doesn't work" does not convey enough information to suggest a solution. You can pass the `-t` option to `lsof` to get terse output (output PID only, omit headers and additional information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "lsof -i:10001 | awk '{print $2}'" };
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec(cmd);
```

that is we run shell with -c option which means that the 3-rd param is shell script string

Comment: It give `exit: 0` but no output is getting printed

Answer (score 0):

You can't use pipes in `Runtime.exec` directly (only by running a `/bin/sh` process and having *it* deal with the piping).  A better approach might be to do just the `lsof` as an external process and then extract the second field in Java code rather than using `awk`.

Also note that the `available()` method returns a number of bytes that the stream knows it could give you right now without blocking, but that doesn't necessarily mean more bytes won't become available later. It is "never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream." ([quote from InputStream JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29)). You need to keep reading until you hit EOF. Apache commons-io provides [useful utility methods](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.InputStream%29) to help with this.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("lsof", "-i:10001");
pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.to(new File("/dev/null")));
Process p = pb.start();
try {
  List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(p.getOutputStream());
  if(lines.size() > 1) {
    // more than one line, so the second (i.e. lines.get(1)) will have the info
    System.out.println(lines.get(1).split("\s+")[1]);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Nothing listening on port 10001");
  }
} finally {
  p.getOutputStream().close();
  p.waitFor();
}
```